# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined-Help me :(

Tags: angular, web-component

I'm writing an Angular project
Linked to the JAVA project I did, I had to import a coupon into a component from the DB to view it to the user.
That's why I created a function to do this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Coupon } from 'src/app/models/coupon';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { CouponsService } from 'src/app/services/coupons.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-coupon-details',
  templateUrl: './coupon-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./coupon-details.component.css']
})
export class CouponDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  public coupon: Coupon;
  public constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute, private couponService : CouponsService) { }

  public ngOnInit() {
    const id = +this.activeRoute.snapshot.params.id;
    this.couponService.getCouponByIdRest(id).subscribe(c => {
    }, err=>{
      console.log("error:", err.message);
    });
  }
}
```

As you can see the function will get an ID at the click and pass us to the coupon that will show us the details of the coupon, the function runs a JAVA function on the server side which returns the coupon according to the ID, and here I encounter an error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' or undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (CouponDetailsComponent.html: 4)

This is the class HTML file:

```
<div >
  <h1>Coupon Details:</h1>

  <h3>Coupon Title: {{coupon.title}}</h3> 
  <h3>Coupon Start Date: {{coupon.startDate}}</h3>
  <h3>End Date: {{coupon.endDate}}</h3>
  <h3>Category: {{coupon.category}}</h3> 
  <h3>Amount: {{coupon.amount}}</h3> 
  <h3>Description: {{coupon.description}}</h3> 
  <h3>Price: {{coupon.price}}</h3>
  <!-- <img style="width: 300px;" src="assets/imagess/products/{{product.id}}.jpg" alt="coupon"> -->
</div>
<div *ngIf="!coupon">
  <h1>Product not found</h1>
</div>
<br>
<button style="font-size: large;" onclick="history.back(-1)">Back to Our-Deals</button>
```

The system does not seem to recognize the coupon? The title?
I checked that everything was listed properly and couldn't find a problem
As you can see I just started writing in angular, if you need more information to help me I'd love to send it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `component` you never assing your `api` response to `coupon` variable like this

```
 this.couponService.getCouponByIdRest(id).subscribe(c => { this.coupon = c}, err=>{
  console.log("error:", err.message);

});
```

And in your component.html you can bind like this

```
<h1>{{coupon?.title}}</h1>
```

Comment: For some reason, it works, but the error still exists in the browser ..
Do you have any idea why?

Comment: what's the error? please specify the error in your question post and also include your `api response` so that i can guide you correctly

Comment: you need to use `coupon?.title` in your template instead of  `coupon.title`

Comment: @MatanElbaz  the reason may be you have not used, "this" keywork. check my answer below

Comment: @MatanElbaz i have updated my answer please check my updated answer

Comment: thank you all guys!!
as @AshotAleqsanyan says, i was just needed to chage coupon.title to coupon?.title 
I would be happy to learn why a question mark should be used in this case??

Comment: @MatanElbaz it will be take the title of coupon in case of coupon is not undefined, t `coupon?.title` equal to this expression `coupon ? coupon.title : ''`

Comment: @MatanElbaz basically when intially your component's `DOM` is loaded in your browser so sometimes data from api takes some time to come and before data arrival your `DOM` has been created for the component but at that time data binding property gets null value that's why it throws an error like `property of undefined`. So `?` is an angular safe navigation operator which prevents browser to show error even if there is no data

Answer (score 0):

You have taken the response from the **getCouponByIdRest** API, but you have not assigned it to **coupon** variable.

Since the html is parsed in the browser, the coupon has nothing but NULL and it is not unidentified and same for its properties.

In order to access the variable, use ***this*** keyword, or else it will not identify the variable.

```
this.couponService.getCouponByIdRest(id).subscribe(c => { this.coupon = c}, err=>{
  console.log("error:", err.message);
});
```

Hope this answer helps you !!